# How to substitute all values of a certain key in an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of JSON object, for example, `people` with data, for example:

```
[
  {
    name : 'John',
    age : '7'
  },
  {
    name : 'Mary',
    age : '70'
  },
  {
    name : 'Joe',
    age : '40'
  },
  {
    name : 'Jenny',
    age : '4'
  }
]
```

I want to substitute all string values in `age` for its corresponding integer in order to sort by `age`. Or to add a key, for example `ageI` with the integer value.

I could loop through the array, but, is there a better way to do that, for example with one command in jQuery?

Comment: Short answer: no, as everything will involve a "loop" of sorts. It could be a "loop" hidden behind a higher-order function/construct, such as with `Array.forEach` or `Array.map` or the equivalent jQuery forms..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to modify the `array` in place:

```js
var array = [
  {
    name : 'John',
    age : '7'
  },
  {
    name : 'Mary',
    age : '70'
  },
  {
    name : 'Joe',
    age : '40'
  },
  {
    name : 'Jenny',
    age : '4'
  }
]


array.forEach(obj => { obj.age = Number(obj.age) });

console.log(array);
```

Or use `map` to make a new array:

```js
var array = [
      {
        name : 'John',
        age : '7'
      },
      {
        name : 'Mary',
        age : '70'
      },
      {
        name : 'Joe',
        age : '40'
      },
      {
        name : 'Jenny',
        age : '4'
      }
    ]
    
console.log(
  array.map(obj => ({ name: obj.name, age: Number(obj.age) }))
);
```

Comment: The `map` solution is less ideal because you'd have to reconstruct the whole object.

Comment: @Purag I guess it depends on the use cases. Some times it has its merits since it doesn't modify the original object.

Comment: Absolutely; if the objects aren't more complicated than what OP has shown, `map` is totally viable! In case the objects are larger the `forEach` is just more reasonable to write. :)

Comment: @Purag Agreed. That's why made the `forEach` solution firstly. And thought I might add `map` as another option. ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to sort, simply sort with a callback

```
arr.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.age, 10) - parseInt(b.age, 10));
```

If you want the values to stay ints, use a simple loop

```
arr.forEach(e => e.age = parseInt(e.age, 10));
```